# Input data to AWS Elastic Search using Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-elasticsearch

I'm looking for a solution to insert data to AWS Elastic Search using AWS Glue python or pyspark. I have seen Boto3 SDK for Elastic Search but could not find any function to insert data into Elastic Search. Can anyone help me to find solution ?
Any useful links or code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For aws glue you need to add an additional jar to the job.

1. Download the jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/7.8.0/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.8.0.jar
2. Save the jar on s3 and pass it to the glue job.
3. Now while saving the dataframe use following

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").\
         option("es.resource", "index/document").\
         option("es.nodes", host).\
         option("es.port", port).\
         save()
```

If you are using aws managed elastic search, try setting this to true

```
option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
```

For more properties check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

**NOTE**
The elasticsearch-spark connector is compatible with spark 2.3 only as it is prebuilt on scala 2.11 while spark 2.4 and spark 3.0 is prebuilt on scala 2.12

Comment: but i'm using spark 2.4