# Unable to connect to AWS Elastic Search from AWS GLUE

Tags: aws-glue, aws-elasticsearch

I am looking to connect to elastic search from AWS Glue. I followed this  [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829791/input-data-to-aws-elastic-search-using-glue), As mentioned in the post we have added the jar file in the s3 bucket and referenced the JAR path while creating the job. When we tried to ingest data to elastic, glue is throwing below error.

Elastic version is 7.1.1 and the jar file we referenced is also the same version elasticsearch-hadoop-7.1.1.jar

**

> An error occurred while calling o116.save. Cannot detect ES version -
> typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not
> accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper
> setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'An error occurred while calling o116.save.
> Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the
> network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a
> WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'**

Here is the code that we used, Are we missing any settings here.

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").\
         option("es.nodes", "endpoint").\
         option("es.port", 443).\
         option("es.resource", "test/_doc").\
         option("es.nodes.wan.only",True).\
         option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true").\
         option("es.net.ssl", "true").\
         option("es.mapping.id","id").\
         save()
```

Comment: Hi! I have the same issue. I am wondering did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

To connect from AWS Glue to Elasticsearch you need an [AWS Glue Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-using.html) of type "NETWORK". In Terraform it can be added by using [aws_glue_connection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_connection). The name - not the ID - of the connection must be added to the list of "connections" from [aws_glue](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job).

```
resource "aws_glue_connection" "elasticsearch" {
  name            = "glue_connection_to_elasticsearch"
  connection_type = "NETWORK"
  ...
end

resource "aws_glue_job" "your_glue_job_name" {
  ...
  connections = [aws_glue_connection.elasticsearch.name]
  ...
end
```